# constrained optimization - to find optimal translation vector in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mathematical-optimization

I am new to optimization problem and gone through several math library like Alglib, DotNumerics and Microsoft Solver Foundation, I have no luck on how to kick start, perhaps some experts can shed some lights.

I wanted to get optimal translation from 3d points on reference contour to target contour.

[image: ref-target-point]

Below is the constrained optimization problem. How do I optimize it if I wish to use DotNumerics for instance, I have no idea how to kickstart:

[image: problem]

- Pr : 3d points on reference contour
- Pt : 3d points on target contour
- t(Pr): translation vector of point Pr  **<-- this is what I looking for**

Below is the example provided by DotNumerics, how should I take all my 3d points as input and churn out translation vector?

```
public void OptimizationLBFGSBConstrained()
{
    //This example minimize the function
    //f(x0,x2,...,xn)= (x0-0)^2+(x1-1)^2+...(xn-n)^2
    //The minimum is at (0,1,2,3...,n) for the unconstrained case.

    //using DotNumerics.Optimization;

    L_BFGS_B LBFGSB = new L_BFGS_B();
    int numVariables = 5;
    OptBoundVariable[] variables = new OptBoundVariable[numVariables];
    //Constrained Minimization on the interval (-10,10), initial Guess=-2; 
    for (int i = 0; i < numVariables; i++) variables[i] = new OptBoundVariable("x" + i.ToString(), -2, -10, 10);
    double[] minimum = LBFGSB.ComputeMin(ObjetiveFunction, Gradient,variables);

    ObjectDumper.Write("L-BFGS-B Method. Constrained Minimization on the interval (-10,10)");
    for (int i = 0; i < minimum.Length; i++) ObjectDumper.Write("x" + i.ToString() + " = " + minimum[i].ToString());

    //Constrained Minimization on the interval (-10,3), initial Guess=-2; 
    for (int i = 0; i < numVariables; i++) variables[i].UpperBound = 3;
    minimum = LBFGSB.ComputeMin(ObjetiveFunction, Gradient, variables);

    ObjectDumper.Write("L-BFGS-B Method. Constrained Minimization on the interval (-10,3)");
    for (int i = 0; i < minimum.Length; i++) ObjectDumper.Write("x" + i.ToString() + " = " + minimum[i].ToString());

    //f(x0,x2,...,xn)= (x0-0)^2+(x1-1)^2+...(xn-n)^2
    //private double ObjetiveFunction(double[] x)
    //{
    //    int numVariables = 5;
    //    double f = 0;
    //    for (int i = 0; i < numVariables; i++) f += Math.Pow(x[i] - i, 2);
    //    return f;
    //}

    //private double[] Gradient(double[] x)
    //{
    //    int numVariables = 5;
    //    double[] grad = new double[x.Length];
    //    for (int i = 0; i < numVariables; i++) grad[i] = 2 * (x[i] - i);
    //    return grad;
    //}
}
```

**Edit 1:**
To make things complicated, I have added the real problem been working on Unity. I sampled 5 iso-contour lines from the reference model and did the same to target model(different mesh and different vertices position) - On first iso-contour on reference model, I sampled 8 normalized points(equally split by distance), still I did the same to the target model. Therefore, I have 2 pairs of corresponding point sets (target model normalized points position will always change given every user has different body size) - Next, I repeat steps mentioned above to cover rest of iso-contours. Once I done that, I will be using formula above to optimize the problem in order to get the optimal translation vector so that I can translate all vertices from reference to target model with **1 single translation vector** (not sure this is possible) - Is this how optimization works?

[image]
 *Please ignore red line in the yellow iso-contour*

Comment: attach marker objects, the entire point of a game engine is it does these transforms for you.